# Android - I don't seem to have the ANIM folder or the MAINANIM.xml document... why is this?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, sdk

No matter where I look in the res directory there is only main.xml and I am supposed to have res/anim/mainanim.xml but I don't have it.

My code is here:
[Frame-by-frame animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290290/please-help-me-with-frame-animaions-android-question)

I also keep getting in the java document, "id and anim cannot be resolved or is not a field" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no default 'mainanim.xml'. The example that was given to you gives you the code. You have to create the directory and the .xml file yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mia, to create the folder, go to where you saved the project on your computer and create the folder yourself and refresh Eclipse. Or in Eclipse, right click on the "res" folder, say new -> folder and name it "anim".