# How can I replicate the back key's slide transition for the drawer back button?

Tags: android, animation

By using `overridePendingTransition(...)` I can set whatever animations I want for my app's drawer back button.  I want to make that animation identical to the back key animation; that is, have the exiting activity slide off right and the entering activity slide in from like 90% or whatever it is.

I assume there's an easy way to do this, like an `android.R.anim.?` entry or something, but I've been unable to find it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem; it turns out that finish() uses the same transition effect as the back key.  I figured I was overthinking things :)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

A fragment animation would have the same issue, but this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own TranslationAnimation.

For example, the following xml is for **sliding in** a view **from the left**.

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

By interchnaging the values of **`XDelta`** , you can get slide out from right as well.

Comment: Do you know of any sources I could peruse to find out what the default back key animation's settings are, or would I need to do trial and error to get it right?

Comment: Which animation are you talking about? The back key has different behaviour in different applications, mostly because the developers override the pending transitions. If slide in left/right is what you are looking for, the code snippet I gave should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't find **android.R.anim** in project is because under res folder anim is missing. To create that Rightclick the **res folder**->**new**->**folder** , create the folder name as **anim** and inside the anim folder create your own xml animation file and use it code as @Swayam said check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293972/android-i-dont-seem-to-have-the-anim-folder-or-the-mainanim-xml-document-w)

Comment: It's not missing, it and all of its animations are present.  This is not a problem. If `android.R.anim` were ever missing, I'd be blaming my SDK installation!